# Class diagram to sequence diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I have a very strange exercise from school and I can't figure it out. I am supposed to change this class diagram (shown on picture) to sequence diagram. But it just doesn't make sense for me as long as it seems that this picture describes just one class.

[image]

Comment: Class diagram is for static structure of the system while sequence diagram is for system behaviour so there's no way to change one into another. Either you have additional description of system behaviour and your goal is to describe that behaviour making sure to use lifelines and message specifications based on your class diagram or your teacher requests something impossible. In general when you're at school you're allowed not to know something and usually it's best to ask the teacher directly. This page is not intended to help with homeworks unless you really have some specific problem.

Comment: You could only make an example sequence. It looks like this should show the implementation of a Facade pattern. Go read about that first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented you can not really convert it, just invent an example. Since it looks like this is a Facade implementation, a good guess would be the following:

[image]

You can see that calls to the `Facade` are forwarded to the subsystems.

Comment: What did you use to create that diagram?

Comment: @PéturIngiEgilsson Enterprise Architect. I guess that can be done with almost all UML tools in similar fashion.

Comment: I believe so, never seen an Actor used like that... is that allowed according to OMG's UML standard? I always use "found" messages indead.

Comment: @PéturIngiEgilsson Sure you can do that. Here the actor is a placeholder for whatever might use the `Facade`. SDs are always "examples" to demonstrate collaboration.

Comment: thank you very much this seems to be good solution. my friend made it the same way. Much appreciated.